# How to insert array data in mysql table using post method

Tags: php, mysql

My Dear friends help me please.

I want to insert array of data in mysql table using post method.
I'm trying but its not working.

I'm new in php please help me and save my time.

Thanks in advance my friends.

Here is my php api.

```
        $key = $_POST['key'];
    $orderId = $_POST['orderId'];

    $orderDetail = $_POST['orderDetail']

     if ($orderDetail != null && $orderId != null)
     {
         $items = array();

         for ($i = 0; $i < count($orderDetail); i++)

             {
                 $item[$i] = [

                 $orderId = $orderId;
                 $foodId=$orderDetail[$i]['foodId'];
                 $foodQuantity =$orderDetail[$i]['foodQuantity'];
                 $foodPrice=$orderDetail[$i]['foodPrice'];
                 0;
                 $foodSize=$orderDetail[$i]['foodSize'];
                 $foodAddon=$orderDetail[$i]['foodAddon'];
                 $foodExtraPrice=$orderDetail[$i]['foodExtraPrice'];

                 ]


             }
     }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO orderDetail(orderId,    foodId , foodQuantity, foodPrice , discount ,foodSize , foodAddon,foodExtraPrice)
    VALUES ('$orderId', '$foodId' , '$foodQuantity'  , '$foodPrice'   , 0  , '$foodSize'    , '$foodAddon'   , '$foodExtraPrice' )";
```

Comment: Run the `INSERT` inside the `FOR`. No need to `$item[$i]`. And the execution of `$sql` is missing

Comment: thanks dear.Can you fix these error for me please

Comment: okay i will pay.

Answer (score 1):

A few things are wrong with your code,

1. your query, it's extremely bad practice to insert data directly into the query, this causes the web's most common security flaw, [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use prepared statements instead.
2. you're not inserting the data to any table, you're just writing a query, you should make a database connection with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-examples) and use [PDO's prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to insert your data to your mysql database.
3. your query can be moved inside the second for, there's no need to use the intermediate array `$items`.
4. you're missing a semicolon after `$orderDetail = $_POST['orderDetail']`.
5. `if ($orderDetail != null && $orderId != null)` is not what you're looking for, you should use [isset](https://php.net/isset) and [empty](https://php.net/empty) instead

EDIT:
this is how your code should look like:

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YOURDBNAMEHERE;host=YOURHOSTHERE', 'YOURUSERNAMEHERE', 'YOURPASSWORDHERE');
if(isset($_POST['orderId']) && isset($_POST['orderDetail']) && !empty($_POST['orderId']) && !empty($_POST['orderDetail'])) {
    $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO orderDetail(orderId, foodId, foodQuantity, foodPrice, discount, foodSize, foodAddon, foodExtraPrice) VALUES(:orderId, :foodId, :foodQuantity, :foodPrice, 0, :foodSize, :foodAddon, :foodExtraPrice)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $orderId = $_POST['orderId'];
    $orderDetail = $_POST['orderDetail'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($orderDetail); i++) {
        $query->execute([
            ":orderId" => $orderId,
            ":foodId" => $orderDetail[$i]['foodId'],
            ":foodQuantity" => $orderDetail[$i]['foodQuantity'],
            ":foodPrice" => $orderDetail[$i]['foodPrice'],
            ":foodSize" => $orderDetail[$i]['foodSize'],
            ":foodAddon" => $orderDetail[$i]['foodAddon'],
            ":foodExtraPrice" => $orderDetail[$i]['foodExtraPrice'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed, good luck with learning PHP :) if there's anything else you don't understand please ask another question here on stackoverflow or checkout php's awesome documentation